# How to get all sheets listed in my organization using SmartSheet API?

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

Is it possible to get all the sheets from my organization when the method only defaults the data result to 100?
https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#list-all-org-sheets

```
// Set the Access Token
Token token = new Token();
token.AccessToken = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ss-token"].ToString();

// Using the Smartsheet builder to create a Smartsheet
SmartsheetClient smartsheet = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(token.AccessToken).Build();
var orgList = smartsheet
    .UserResources // Gets All Org Sheets
    .SheetResources
    .ListSheets(); // no overloads for this method
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've discovered a bug with the C# SDK.  i.e., the method `smartsheet.UserResources.SheetResources.ListSheets()` should give you the ability to specify an input parameter that would result in the `?includeAll=true` querystring parameter/value being added to the Request URL.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like this functionality has been implemented in the SDK.

If you're so inclined, you could download the SDK source code from GitHub and modify that source code to add this functionality. The request URL for getting the "List All Org Sheets" operation to return all results in a single response would be:

`https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/users/sheets?includeAll=true`

(I've made note of this bug, so that we can address it in a future update to the SDK -- timeframe TBD. In the meantime, if you do end up fixing it yourself, please do submit a pull request via GitHub so that others may benefit from your fix as well.)